# Neutrinos from a Type 1a Supernova

Tags: neutrinos, supernova

How much energy does a Type Ia Supernova produce in the form of neutrinos?

I know that a Type II Supernova produces around $10^{45}$ joules worth of neutrinos, but not the amount produced by a Type 1a supernova.

Also, how far away could we detect the neutrinos from the explosion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is expected to be a $\sim 1$ second burst of neutrinos peaking at around $10^{43}$ W ([Kunugise and Iwanamoto 2007](https://academic.oup.com/pasj/article/59/6/L57/1512997)). [Wright et al. (2017)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07403) present simulations for gravitationally confined detonations and deflagration scenarios that only produce $10^{41}$–$2\times10^{42}$ joules. So about $10^4$ times less energy in neutrinos than a core collapse supernova.

The neutrinos are released via electron captures onto free protons and neutron-rich iron-peak nuclei produced in the explosion. The neutrinos have energies of a few MeV, which is a bit lower than the $\sim 10$ MeV neutrinos expected from core collapse supernova.

Wright, et al. (2017) suggest that the larger values they obtain would be detectable by the largest neutrino detectors, like Hyper-Kamiokande if they were closer than the Galactic centre (8 kpc), but possibly only out to about$\sim 1 $ kpc, depending on the exact explosion mechanism. i.e. Certainly not if the supernova were as far away as the Large Magellanic Cloud like the core collapse supernova SN1987a.